# Append data to the end of a specific line in text file

Tags: bash, sed

I admit to being a novice in bash script, but can't quite seem to figure out how to accomplish a key step in a script and couldn't quite find what I was looking for in other threads.

I am trying to extract some specific data (numerical values) from multiple .xml files and add those to a space or tab delimited text file. The files will be generated over time so I need a way to append a new dataset to the pre-existing text file.

For instance, I would like to extract values for 3 different categories, 1 per row or column, and the value for each category from multiple xml files. Basically, I want to build a continuous graph of the data from each of 3 categories over time.

I have the following code which will successfully extract the 3 numbers from the xml file and trim the unnecessary text:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    grep "<observation name=\"meanGhost\" type=\"float\">" "/Users/Erik/MRI/PHANTOM/2/phantom_qa/summaryQA.xml" \

    | sed 's/<observation name=\"meanGhost\" type=\"float\">//g' \

    | sed 's/<\/observation>//g' >> $HOME/Desktop/testxml.txt


    grep "<observation name=\"meanBrightGhost\" type=\"float\">" "/Users/Erik/MRI/PHANTOM/2/phantom_qa/summaryQA.xml" \

    | sed 's/<observation name=\"meanBrightGhost\" type=\"float\">//g' \

    | sed 's/<\/observation>//g' >> $HOME/Desktop/testxml.txt


    grep "<observation name=\"std\" type=\"float\">" "/Users/Erik/MRI/PHANTOM/2/phantom_qa/summaryQA.xml" \

    | sed 's/<observation name=\"std\" type=\"float\">//g' \

    | sed 's/<\/observation>//g' >> $HOME/Desktop/testxml.txt
```

This gives the output:

> 1.12
>
> 0.33
>
> 134.1

I would like to then read in another xml file to get:

> 1.12    1.45
>
> 0.33    0.54
>
> 134.1   144.1

I would be grateful for any help with doing this! Thanks in advance.

Erik

Answer (score 1):

It's much safer to use proper XML handling tools. For example, in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write something like

```
$f1 := open /Users/Erik/MRI/PHANTOM/2/phantom_qa/summaryQA.xml ;
$f2 := open /path/to/the/second/file.xml ;

echo ($f1 | $f2)//observation[@name="meanGhost"] ;
echo ($f1 | $f2)//observation[@name="meanBrightGhost"] ;
echo ($f1 | $f2)//observation[@name="std"] ;
```